# Boolean Formula Satisfiability - Solving with Minimum Amount of Variables Set to True

Tags: boolean-logic, satisfiability

I am having trouble coming up with the pseudocode to solve the Boolean satisfiability problem using the minimum amount of variables set to true.

I have a method satisfiable number(H) that I can call to obtain the minimum number of variables needed to be set to true in order for the Boolean formula to be satisfiable.

```
find-sat-min(f) {
if (not SAT(f)) return 0

L = {x | x is variable in f};
S = {};
int trueCount = 0;

for (x in L) {
    if (SAT(f ^ x) && trueCount < satisfiable number(f)) {
        S = S U {x};
        f = f ^ x;
        trueCount++;
    }
    else {
        S = S U {NOT x};
        f = f ^ NOT x;
    }
}

return S;
```

}

Here's my current logic. Please let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: What is satisfiable_num(f) ?

Comment: What does 'satisfiable_num' do?

Comment: I made an error. satisfiable_num refers to satisfiable number(H). Fixed.

Comment: What is "minimal number variables"?  Do you mean minimal number of variables?

Comment: Yes sorry about that error. I do mean minimal number of variables.

Comment: This is a instance of a more general problem called [MaxSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem). (This is actually **partial** maxsat.) This problem has a long history and a large amount of literature, and a yearly [competition](http://maxsat.ia.udl.cat/introduction/).

Comment: I am guessing that "satisfiable number(f)" returns the minimum number of variables need to be set to true to satisfy a problem. (I am not sure why you use such a powerful oracle. This seems just as hard as the original problem.) Notice that the current algorithm is greedy. Suppose L = <a,b,c>, and f = (a ^ b ^ c) v (~a ^ b ^ ~c). Initially, "satisfiable number(f)" is 1 and the current solution selects a, then b, then c. But the minimum answer is ~a, b, ~c.